# Research Topics for Advanced High School Students

Tags: soft-question, research

I am currently a junior attending a small high school that requires a project called senior thesis. Each one of us will have to come up with a topic/question on our own, work on the project and do research for an entire school year, and present it in May.

For some background.

- I have mastered all standard high school mathematics.
- I got a 5 on AP Calc BC last year, hence I am decently proficient in single variable calculus.
- I am working on AP Stats this year.
- I have been working on some real analysis and have been making good progress.
- I have learned some linear and abstract algebra, but perhaps just the most basic things.
- Set theory and mathematical logic have been some of my favorites. I have spent quite some time on those topics.
- I do not really have any background in geometry or topology beyond high school geometry or the topology required in analysis courses.
- I have learned a bit of number theory and probability theory beyond the high school requirement.
- I am taking AP Physics 1 this year.

All that to say, I'm looking for a topic/question that is not too easy nor too hard for me. Here are my thoughts on what the topic/question might be.

- I'm willing to learn more stuff and challenge myself in the research process (after all, that is what research actually is).
- The topic can be in any area of math (or even physics), but preferably the ones that I'm more comfortable with.
- The topic/question should have some real life application if possible. The application does not have to be in everyday life (aka. it could be complicated).
- The topic/question should take me about 6 months or so to fully solve. That is, if I start learning new concepts or techniques in September, then I should be able to fully understand and solve it in around February.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't mention any "ability" in programming ?

Comment: @Marie Thank you for pointing that out. I have used some python and sage for programming, but still I am not very fluent, although I am happy to learn. I am also proficient in LaTeX and have used it for my school assignments many times.

Comment: I advise you to look for a transversal project including different aspects. For example 1) Voronoi tesselations and Delaunay triangulations, 2) the domain of "Geometry of numbers" (created by Minkovski) relying on convexity. 3) Some aspects of graph theory 4) families of curves and their envelopes 5) Complex numbers and their generalisation with quaternions, etc.